# Adjusting image parameters in Delphi (Mitov VideoLab)

Tags: delphi, video-capture, brightness, webcam-capture

I made a little application in `Delphi XE3`, using `Mitov VideoLab`.
I have `VLDSCapture` component which captures the video from my webcam.
Also I have `VLDSImageDisplay` component to display the captured preview.
What I want to do, is adjust i.e. Brightness, i.e. on each click of the button to increase Brightness for 10. I can access the `VLDSCapture1.Adjustment.Brightness.Value`, but when I increase it using this line on button click:

```
VLDSCapture1.Adjustment.Brightness.Value := VLDSCapture1.Adjustment.Brightness.Value + 30;
```

nothing happens with the captured preview.

Do I need to somehow notify one of these 2 components that there is change of the brightness value or what?

I know this is 3rdparty library, and I have contacted the creator, but haven't received any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that I missed was to set `Enabled` to true in `Adjustment` section of `VLDSCapture` ...